# Seach the info in Realtime Database and show in cards React and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search multiple products in the realtime database and show then in cards, I've been searching but haven't found much.

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Card from './components/Card/card';
import './App.css';
import { database } from "./firebase";
import { ref, onValue  } from "firebase/database"

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ref1 = ref(database, 'main'); 

    onValue(ref1, (snapshot) => {
      setData(snapshot.val())
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul className="horizontal-menu">
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div className="card-grid">
        {data.map(item => (
            <Card
              title={item.Title}
              image={item.Image_URL}
              Description={item.Description}
            />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My database is like this:

```
main   
|   
|__ 1
      |__ Title: "Products 1"
      |__ Image_URL: "https://example.com/Products1.jpg"
      |__ Description: 'Product 1'
```

Comment: This is quite well document in the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and in many of the existing [questions on querying the realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+query).